# WMI Win32_OperatingSystem OSArchitecture field causes exception

Tags: .net, wmi

I am trying to get information on the version of Windows installed from WMI. Most fields work. I can get the operating system "Name" as well as the "Version", both are fields of the Win32_OperatingSystem object I have.

But another field "OSArchitecture" generates an exception ("Not found").

```
    strScope = "\\" + strServer + "\root\CIMV2"
    searcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(strScope, "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")

    For Each mo In searcher.Get

        strOSName = mo("Name")
        strOSVersion = mo("Version")
        strOSArchitecture = mo("OSArchitecture")
        strStatus = mo("Status")
        strLastBoot = mo("LastBootUpTime")

    Next
```

The documentation says that the field ought to exist and is a String:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(VS.85).aspx

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be a stupid question...are you running the query on a win32 OS...I'm thinking it might not be there if it's a x64

Comment: It's running on 32 bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original question had the line:

```
strOSArchitecture = mo("Architecture")
```

which should have been:

```
strOSArchitecture = mo("OSArchitecture")
```

Now that you've confirmed that was a simple typo in the question (not your actual code), the other likelihood is that you are running on either Server 2003, 2000, NT4, XP or Me/98/95, where the documentation lists the `OSArchitecture` key as unavailable?

Comment: Sorry, it actually did. I pasted the wrong version of the code after I was trying to fix this by trying out different names. The exception happens with "OSArchitecture". I'll edit my question.

Comment: I am realising now that it depends on the target machine. I wrote a small program moTest using Gimel's idea and ran it against a 2003 and a 2008 machine. The 2008 machine returned a mo that had an OSArchitecture property and the 2003 machine returned a mo that had no OSArchitecture property.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to remove the correction of the property name and contain only the actual answer?

Answer (score 1):

To view a current (runtime) list of available properties, walk the `Properties` attribute.
In a console application, it looks like:

```
For Each mo In searcher.Get
    Console.WriteLine("..." + mo.Properties.Count.ToString() + " properties")
    For Each prop In mo.Properties
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name)
    Next
    '...
```

On my XP installation, no `OSArchitecture` appears in the 61 property names listed.

Comment: That would explain the exception. But since the actual native WMI class defines such a field (OSArchitecture) why wouldn't it be there as a property? Bug in the bridge?